# What is Better for User Role Management? Sql Server user Role or Custom User Role?

Tags: sql, sql-server, access-control, user-roles

We are working on a new project , which we intended to be following one of the best security and access control mechanism.
We are opting whether to use application custom roles or user role of SQL Server.
We need hierarchical ordering of roles maintaining row level security.
As of sql there is no built in support for hierarchy and a toolkit as found in Codeplex, SQL Server Label Toolkit, which we found appealing but still not sure what to follow. 
What would be the best way to achieve it?

Comment: SQL roles can be members of other SQL roles, so you can have a hierarchy. It's just that SQL doesn't enforce a *strict* tree-like structure, because roles can be members of multiple other roles.

Comment: So What would you suggest, using user and roles of sql server or custom application user role.

Comment: I would suggest custom application user role